# How does datamaps display images instead of bubbles?

Tags: d3.js, datamaps

I use the following code to display bubbles on datamaps. I want to show images instead of colored bubbles. How can I implement it?

```
 var bubs = [];             
 for (var ix in newsData) { 
   bubs.push({              
     name: newsData[ix].id, 
     latitude: newsData[ix].latitude,                       
     longitude: newsData[ix].longitude,                     
     radius: 18,            
     fillKey: 'gt50',       
     title: newsData[ix].title                              
   });                      
 };                         

 map.bubbles(bubs, {        
   popupTemplate: function(geo, data) {                     
     return "<div class='hoverinfo'><strong>" + geo.title + "</strong></div>";                                              
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is not possible out of the box. But check out the [datamaps-icons-plugin](https://github.com/jdlubrano/datamaps-icons-plugin). Alternatively there is the [datamaps-custom-marker](https://github.com/arshad/datamaps-custom-marker) plugin.